# Java - Output has changed when parameters (arguments) inserted

Tags: java

For the following code, after I inserted parameters "A2 a" and "B2 b" in class A2 and class B2, the output has changed. I wonder why?

**A1 Class:**

```
public class A2 
{
    public void m1(A2 a)
    {
        System.out.println("A2");
    }

}
```

**B2 Class:**

```
public class B2 extends A2 
{
    public void m1(B2 b)
    {
        System.out.println("B2");
    }

}
```

**Main Class (run the program):**

```
public class D2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A2 x = new A2();
        A2 y = new B2();
        B2 z = new B2();

        y.m1();
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume this is not the latest version of `D2` or it wouldn't compile. What argument did you pass to `m1`?

Answer (score 1):

Before you inserted the parameters, `B2.m1()` overrode `A2.m1()`, so the method called depended only on the runtime type of the receiver.

After you inserted the parameters, the two `m1` methods have different type signatures and `B2.m1(B2 b)` no longer overrides `A2.m1(A2 a)`. With that the method called depends on the compile-time types of both the reciever and the parameter being sent.

Given:

```
   A2 x = new A2();
   A2 y = new B2();
   B2 z = new B2();

   y.m1(x);  // calls A2.m1(A2 a)
   y.m1(z);  // calls A2.m1(A2 a)
   z.m1(x);  // calls A2.m1(A2 a)
   z.m1(z);  // calls B2.m1(B2 b)
```

Before you added the parameter:

```
   y.m1();    // would have called B2.m1()
```

Is that the discrepancy you are seeing?

**EDIT**: All too gory details added below.

First you can think of the signature as basically the namea of the method combined with the number
and types of the formal parameters. You may see them written in a form like "m1:(LA2;)V" or "m1:(LB2;)V"
(a method named "m1" that takes 1 parameter of class type `A2` and returns Void). But here I'll just
write `m1(A2)` or `m1(B2)` to make it easier.

There are basically two steps for determining what method finally gets called. A compile-time step
and a run-time step. The compile-time step determines the signature of the method to be called. The
run-time step picks the actual method to invoke by finding the one with that signature is the class
of the object as it was created. If it doesn't find it there it moves up the class hierachy until a
method with that signature is found (there has to be one somewhere or it wouldn't have compiled).

To find the signature, the compile-time types (also called the "static types") are used (the ones
used to declare the variable). This goes for both the receiver and the parameters.

So let's look at the signatures chosen in each case:

```
y.m1(x)
```

y is declared to be an `A2` so the only possible signature is `m1(A2)`.

```
y.m1(z)
```

Again, `y` is an `A2` so the only possibility is `m1(A2)`. The fact that `z` is a `B2` is fine since
you can always pass a `B2` where an `A2` is expected. (At this point in the process, the fact that
at run-time `y` will be created as a `B2` is irrelevant!)

```
z.m1(x)
```

`z` is a `B2`. In `B2` there are two possibilities. `m1(B2)` and the inherited `m1(A2)`. Since `x`
is an `A2`, the first is not possible (you can't pass an `A2` where a `B2` is expected), so once
again we are left with `m1(A2)`.

```
z.m1(z)
```

`z` is a `B2`. In `B2` there are two possibilities. `m1(B2)` and the inherited `m1(A2)`. Since `z`
is a `B2`, both are possible. Here Java has a rule for choosing which is to take the one with the
most specific (most derived) argument type, so `m1(B2)` is chosen.

In all of the above cases, there is nothing more to decide at runtime since in each case there is
only one method with the given signature. Take the case of `y.m1(z)`. At runtime Java will look for
the method with signature `m1(A2)` as determined in the compile-time step.

First it will look in class `B2` since `y` was created as a `B2` object. But here there is no method
with that signature (there is only `m1(B2)`).  It doesn't matter that `z` is a `B2` object, once the
signature is determined in the compile-time step, only a method with that signature will be called
at run-time. So Java goes up the hierarchy and finds a method with the right signature in class
`A2`, and hence the results are what you are seeing. (Note that this is conceptual and the actual
code generated to get it to the right method is a bit more clever than that.)

Now before you added the parameter, both m1 methods were named "m1" and had no parameters, hence they had
the same signature `m1()`. So looking at

```
y.m1()
```

Compile-time step:  `y` is an `A2` so the only possibility to be chosen is m1().

Then at runtime, since `y` was created as a `B2`, Java starts in class `B2` looking for a method
with that signature.  It finds one! The `m1()` method in `B2` has the same signature as the `m1()`
method in `A2`. In other words, unlike the cases above, `B2`.m1 truly overrides `A2.m1`. So java is
happy to call the version of `m1()` in `B2`, as you saw before you added the parameters.

So that's the story. I know it's confusing but it's really key to understanding Java (and other object
oriented languages) and great that you are digging in to this.

Read everything you can about overriding vs. overloading, polymorphism, dynamic dispatch and virtual
method tables.

I think the most important points are:

-- Only if you override a method do you get dynamic dispatching based on the run-time
   type of the receiver

-- A method in a derived class only overrides a method in the base class if the signature
   is the same

Comment: yes, you're spot on, but I still don't understand how could a simple parameter change the output. I don't see any correlation between the parameters and the output. Would you do a step-by-step code trace to explain the problem? What are the 2 type signatures after the parameters inserted?

Answer (score 0):

`y.m1()` now requires a parameter to be passed to the method.  Does this code even compile?  Since you've constructed y to be a B2 object, calling `y.m1()` will run the code in the B2 object as opposed to the A2 object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html